# Powershell inside AutohotKey is not working

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I can run any PowerShell command inside AHK file. For example, this command below:

```
Run, PowerShell.exe -noexit -Command "Start notepad; start calc.exe",, hide
```

I have Powershell command that I can run it from PowerShell fine and its working great which will add user as local admin on remote machine:

```
([ADSI]"WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators,Group").Add("WinNT://HMM.org.br/Paul1")
```

However, when I use the above code on AHK like it's not working!

```
Run, PowerShell.exe -noexit -Command "([ADSI]"WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators,Group").Add("WinNT://HMM.org.br/Paul1")",, hide
```

I keep getting this error:

> At line:1 char:8<>
>   + ([ADSI]WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   Unexpected token 'WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators' in expression or statement.
>   At line:1 char:8
>   + ([ADSI]WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators
>   +        ~
>   Missing closing ')' in expression.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Can anyone advice on what to do? I could write external file PS1 and call it from the AHK then delete it, but I want to have it running from my single AHK file.

Comment: Not really familiar with AutoHotKey, but you need to escape the double-quote characters within the command. Possibly using a backtick `\`` or a backslash: `Run, PowerShell.exe -noexit -Command "([ADSI]\`"WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators,Group\`").Add(\`"WinNT://HMM.org.br/Paul1\`")",, hide`

Comment: Could also drop the `"` entirely and just do `"([ADSI]'WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators,Group').Add('WinNT://HMM.org.br/Paul1')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Run, powershell.exe -noexit -command ([ADSI]\"WinNT://serverabc123/Administrators`,Group\").Add(\"WinNT://HMM.org.br/Paul1\")
```

That is:

- Don't use outer quoting.
- `\`-escape `"` characters (required by PowerShell)
- `` ` ``-escape `,` characters (required by AutoHotkey)

Comment: @shadad: My pleasure; glad to hear it helped; indeed, the solution is not exactly obvious.